# Request["http_cookie"] is giving OutlookSession={.....}?

Tags: c#, cookies

I am storing the value of user `Cookie` using `Request["http_cookie"]` in my database.

But i found that some of the column of my cookie were empty and other contains cookie as  **OutlookSession={.....}**  but why ?

**EDIT**  Also `Request["http_user_agent"];`   is `Microsoft Office/14.0 (Windows NT 5.1; Microsoft Outlook 14.0.6123; Pro)`

Comment: How do you visit the URL? What does [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) say about the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request["http_cookie"] is actually not getting your a cookie from the HTTP header but from http_cookie parameter in your request , ether form or query string. This scenario is no part of a HTTP standard it related to your application logic.

Comment: I think you are right. but I have no knowledge of the application logic as it was built by someone else in siteCore and I am not familiar with it. I just need to work this out so can you tell me how can I get the correct values for all request variables like  `http_cookie ,http_user_agent etc`

Comment: You need to use Request.Header see for examples http://www.dotnetperls.com/request-headers

Comment: but to get the `http_cookie` and all other variables i need to check every key in the loop or there is a direct way?

Comment: Request.Headers["http_cookie"]

Comment: `Request.Headers["http_cookie"]`  is null :(

Comment: By standard cookie is stored in Cookie header so use Request.Headers["Cookie"]

Comment: thanks  i just found out that.. providing braeakpoint and looking the variable headers but rally thanks a ton. now lets check it on live